# I need my ReactJS app working offline without server

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have simple one page html/js/ReactJS app which is used with the help of such scripts added to index.html. It is running without any server, because client needs it to be used only on his computer:

```
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"</script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make this app working offline? I can use Node Server, but when application is downloaded by client it needs to be opened using the only `index.html` file.

Comment: You could look into electron, it lets you bundle and run a web page as a native desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the three files above:

- `react` : https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js
- `react-dom` : https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
- `babel` : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js

You can do this by going to the src links in your script tags above, right-click the webpage, click `Save As`, choose file type as JavaScript and then replace the above src links in your index.html to those downloaded files.

You can create a special folder for the site and within the folder, you can paste a copy of your index.html file as well as a js folder and keep the above three downloaded JavaScript files in that js folder.

You can now simply replace the src link in the above three scripts tags like this:

```
<script src="js/react.production.min.js" />
<script src="js/react-dom.production.min.js" />
<script src="js/babel.min.js" />
```

---

However, this only works if the client is just viewing the site. If the client wants to say, edit the files and want something like `hot reload`, they will need to set up a server for that.